# inverse Fourier of power function

Tags: fourier-transform

I want to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of the following statement:
$$(-ika)^{-B}(ik+A)^{-c}$$
I used convolution theorem.$F^{-1}((-ika)^{-B}*F^{-1}((ik+A)^{-c})$.

$$F^{-1}((ik+A)^{-c})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ikx}(ik+A)^{-c}dk=\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{(-x)^{c-1}e^{Ax}}{Γ(c)}$$
What are you suggesting for this phrase $F^{-1}(-ika)^{-B}$

Comment: How is the inverse fourier transform defined? Have you tried evaluating it for $(-ik)^{\nu}$?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ikx}(-ik)^{\upsilon} dk$

Comment: Should I divide the $\upsilon$ power into even and odd numbers?

Comment: If $\upsilon$ is negative, what is the answer?

Comment: @Mark Viola, are you sure?

Comment: @MarkViola You can subtract some poles to extend $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-zx}dx, \Re(z) > 0,\Re(s) > 0$ to $\Re(z) > 0,\Re(s) > 0$, then let $z \to i \omega$ and see what you get for the limit in the sense of distributions. The alternative is to pick $\Re(s) > 0$ obtaining the FT of $x^{s-1}1_{x > 0}$ from $\lim_{z \to i\omega}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-zx}dx$ then use the Fourier inversion theorem.

Comment: @reuns What did you mean by extend $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-zx}\,dx$, $\text{Re}(z)>0$, $\text{Re}(s)>0$ to $\text{Re}(z)>0$, $\text{Re}(s)>0$.

Comment: @MarkViola A typo I meant $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} (e^{-zx}-\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{z^k}{k!} x^k 1_{x < 1}) dx$ converges for $\Re(s) > -K-1$

Answer (score 1):

The inverse Fourier Transform of $F(k)\equiv \text{sgn}(k)$, is given by

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{\text{sgn}\}(x)&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sgn}(k)e^{-ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 (-1)e^{(a-ix)k}\,dk+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{(-a-ix)k}\,dk \right)\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac1{ix}
\end{align}$$

The $n$'th ordered derivative of the inverse Fourier Transform of $F(k)$ is given by

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\mathscr{F}\{F\}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-ik)^nF(k)e^{-ikx}\,dk$$

whence we find that the inverse Fourier Transform of $(-ik)^n\text{sgn}(k)$ is

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-ik)^n\text{sgn}(k)e^{ikx}\,dk&=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac1x \right)\\\\
&=(-1)^n\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac{n!}{ix^{n+1}}
\end{align}$$

Finally, we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(i\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\frac{(ik)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\text{sgn}(k)\right)e^{-ikx}\,dk=\frac1{x^n}$$